# Oracle PL/SQL public variable with db link in package body

Tags: oracle, plsql, global-variables, dblink, plsql-package

I'm trying to use a global variable in package body with db link but SQLDeveloper throws me PL:00352

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY my_package
    AS
      global_variable ANOTHER_TABLE@MY_DB_LINK.ANOTHER_FIELD%TYPE;
    
      PROCEDURE my_procedure IS
       variable1 my_table.my_field%TYPE;
      BEGIN
       do things;
      END;
    END my_package;
```

The global_variable line is throwing me PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'MY_DB_LINK';

Maybe I am wrong with syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax.

Example: my database link *works*:

```
SQL> select * from dual@dbl_scott;

D
-
X
```

Declaring a variable that *inherits* datatype from `emp` table, `empno` column, over the database link:

```
SQL> declare
  2    gl_var emp.empno@dbl_scott%type;
  3  begin
  4    null;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

So, it is: `table.column@database_link%type`

In your case:

```
global_variable another_table.another_field@my_db_link%type;
```